Как перехватывать не нужные сообщения пользователя в бот? Aiogram 3
Всем, привет! Как начинающий бото-строитель прошу помощи. Весь диалог пользователя с ботом построен на кнопках ReplyKeyboard, InlineKeyboard. Естественно все кнопки отрабатывают хендлеры @dp.message и @dp.callback_query. А как поймать 'рандомное' сообщение от пользователя и ответить, например, - 'Моя твоя не понимать. Нажми кнопу'. Благодарю за ответ.

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT), который будет реагировать на текстовые сообщения пользователя, не соответствующие другим обработчикам.
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram import executor
import logging

# Устанавливаем уровень логгирования
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Инициализируем бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token="YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())

# Обработчик для случайных текстовых сообщений
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT)
async def handle_random_message(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Моя твоя не понимать. Нажми на кнопку.")

# Обработчик для Inline кнопок
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def handle_callback_query(callback_query: CallbackQuery):
    # Ваш код обработки Inline кнопок здесь
    await callback_query.answer()

# Запускаем бота
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)


Благодарю за помощь! У меня установлена версия aiogram 3.5 и возникает проблема  from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware. Контриба нет, не устанавливается. Как теперь исправить эту ситуацию. Спасибо.

@diasporx из данного кода вам по сути нужен только хэндлер @dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT), который должен распологаться под всеми остальными хэндлерами в вашем коде. Если сообщение отправленное боту не будет перехвачено ни одним из других вышестоящих хэндлеров, то как раз таки и отработает хэндлер из примера выше

Благодарю. Во всем разобрался, всё заработало.
